# Apply function element-wise

Tags: python, pandas, python-xarray

In xarray, how can I apply a non-vectorize, non-universal function to a DataArrray, such that I can map each element in the values to a new one ? The custom function shall take a scalar value and return a scalar value:

```py
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

def custom_function(x):
    # imagine some non-vectorized, non-numpy-ufunc stuff
    return type(x) # dummy example function

data = xr.DataArray([1, 2, 3, 4], dims='x')

# this doesn't work, custom_function actually gets send the whole array [1, 2, 3, 4]
# xr.apply_ufunc(custom_function, data)

# I'd expect something like this, where this is basically a loop on all elementss
# xr.apply(custom_function, data)

# in pandas, I would just use the .apply or .map method of Series
import pandas as pd
s = data.to_series()
s.apply(custom_function)
s.map(custom_function)
```

Comment: Have you tried [`apply_ufunc`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.apply_ufunc.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using apply_ufunc as suggested, I get the expected result with `vectorize=True`:

```py
data = xr.DataArray([1, 2, 3, 4], dims='x')
# xr.apply_ufunc(custom_function, data) # fails, equivalent to vectorize=False
xr.apply_ufunc(custom_function, data, vectorize=True) # working
```

```
<xarray.DataArray (x: 4)>
array([<class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>],
      dtype=object)
Dimensions without coordinates: x
```

Explanation: using `vectorize=True` wraps the custom_function with `numpy.vectorize`, basically turning it into a for-loop, which is what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

you can apply a custom function element-wise to a DataArray by using the **apply_ufunc** method with **vectorize=False**

Like this :

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

def custom_function(x):
    # Your custom non-vectorized function here
    scalar_output = x * 2
    return scalar_output

data = xr.DataArray([1, 2, 3, 4], dims='x')

# Apply the custom function element-wise
result = xr.apply_ufunc(custom_function, data, vectorize=False)

print(result)
```

Output :

```
<xarray.DataArray (x: 4)>
array([2, 4, 6, 8])
Dimensions without coordinates: x
```

**[EDIT]**
You can achieve this by converting the DataArray to a pandas Series, applying your custom function, and then converting it back to a DataArray. Here's how you can do it:

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

def custom_function(x):
    scalar_output = x * 2
    return scalar_output

data = xr.DataArray([1, 2, 3, 4], dims='x')

# Convert DataArray to pandas Series
data_series = data.to_series()

# Apply custom function to each element
result_series = data_series.apply(custom_function)

# Convert the result back to a DataArray
result = xr.DataArray(result_series, dims='x')

print(result)
```

Output:

```
<xarray.DataArray (x: 4)>
array([2, 4, 6, 8], dtype=int64)
Coordinates:
  * x        (x) int64 0 1 2 3
```

Comment: Are you sure its vectorize=False and not vectorize=True ?

Comment: Yes. Because when vectorize=False, custom_function is called individually for each element of the DataArray, which is what you want for non-vectorized functions.

Comment: Seems to be the opposite for example if custom_functino returns type(x). I'll update my question according to this case

Comment: Check my update

Answer (score 0):

Or another brainstorming idea: **list comprehension**.

**PS:**

- While **list comprehension** is straightforward for simple cases, it doesn't handle metadata or dimension information automatically. You need to manage these aspects manually if they are important for your use case.
- If you are working primarily with xarray DataArrays and want to maintain dimension and metadata information, **apply_ufunc** is the more appropriate choice. However, for more general cases or when you need more fine-grained control over the operation, a **list comprehension** can be a suitable option.

**Snippet:**

```
result_values = [custom_function(x) for x in data.values]
result = xr.DataArray(result_values, dims='x')
```

**Sample Code:**

```
import xarray as xr

def custom_function(x):
    scalar_output = x * 2
    return scalar_output

data = xr.DataArray([1, 2, 3, 4], dims='x')

# Apply the custom function element-wise using a list comprehension
result_values = [custom_function(x) for x in data.values]
result = xr.DataArray(result_values, dims='x')

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
<xarray.DataArray (x: 4)>
array([2, 4, 6, 8])
Dimensions without coordinates: x
```